# Where do I get "valid Oauth 2.0 token for the service account of the Firebase project"

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, push-notification, firebase-authentication

I'm using Firebase to send push notification.
I successfully set up my project and Firebase console and tested sending notifications through the Firebase console. All work great. Now I'm trying to send notification directly from the app using [this guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message)

The code:

```
    let parameters: [String : Any] = [
        "message": [
            "notification" : [
                "title": "FCM Message",
                "body": "This is an FCM Message"
            ],
            "token" : deviceToken
        ]
    ]

    let headers: [String : String] = [
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Authorization": "Bearer I_NEED_THIS_TOKEN"
    ]

    Alamofire.request("https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/my_project_name/messages:send", method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON { (resp) in
        print(resp.result.value)
    }
```

Seems that to make the code work I only need a valid Oauth 2.0 token for the service account of the Firebase project. But I don't understand where I can get or request it.

So the question is where/how do I get valid Oauth 2.0 token for the service account of the Firebase project.

Comment: can you show how you got the actual token? I'm the same as you where I've got everything ready but nothing shows how to get the token except for in Node. How did you get an Oauth bearer token in code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your FCM Server Key can be found on the Cloud Messaging tab of your project settings on the FCM Admin console.

See https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/auth-server for details.

> Make sure this is the server key, whose value is available in the Cloud Messaging tab of the Firebase console Settings pane. Android, iOS, and browser keys are rejected by FCM.